Is it time to end the allure of acquiring SO "rep points"?
Context:
This page directs any who would answer a low-quality question with (abridged):

Not all questions can or should be answered here ... avoid trying to answer questions which...
...are unclear...
...have already been asked and answered many times before.

Further, the recent VonC incident has prompted several users to make submissions on SO-Meta that imply "acquiring rep points" may have been a temptation that lead to that fiasco.

Why I am posting this to SO-Meta:
I am struggling to wrap-my-head-around activities on this SO question posted 2024-05-02.
At the time of writing, the Q&A has

70+ views,
1 DV and 1 VTC,
2 UV'd "answers" (one with 7 UVs),
a derisive comment to the OP that has a single "thumbs up",
a "buried" reply (comment) from the OP showing they'd worked out their own solution.


Noteworthy:

the word "cast" ("casting") appears 5 times in the title and body of the question,
2 lines of OP's code demonstrate attempts to cast (and dereference) an existing pointer to a different type.


Timeline:

11:00 - the "question" was posted.

11:06 - an "answer" was posted.

11:08 - a comment to the "question" was posted expressing question's poor quality.

11:14 - a second "answer" was posted.

11:22 - the OP commented on one "answer", showing the casting syntax the OP is going forward with.
To date, the OP has either neglected or declined to "accept" either of the two proffered answers.
The (technically correct) "answer" with the most UVs -- answers a question that was not asked.
The code proposed in the "7 UV'd answer" had been explicitly rejected by the OP's origin statement:

OP: "...by declaring a pointer to a matrix of said size, which works, but it kind of defeats the purpose of..."

The "answer" does not address the syntax of casting a pointer that seems to be the OP's question.1
Disregarding its unsettling language, the comment to the OP, posted only 2 minutes after the user posted an "answer", assesses the OP's question as "hard to comprehend" [my paraphrase].

"I supplied an answer to the question you appear to be asking" [emphasis mine].

Possible translation: "After guessing your intent I posted an answer below."

Possible pre-existing SO solutions(?)
Making use of some recent free time, I've found this
2012 question with its single accepted answer, and this
2012 answer.
Both seem to me to convey solutions strongly related to what I had surmised to be the OP's problem.
My sense is there are more -- perhaps even better -- Q&A's already in the repository.

Summary

The OP's posting does not contain a statement recognisable as a question. One - only one - DV and one VTC for the posting.
The technically correct "answer" answers a quasi-related, but different, question with information that the OP has stated is already known to them.
Derision of the question was leveled in a comment posted two minutes after the "answer" was posted; "answer" and subsequent comment both from the same author.
More than a week later, this exchange still stands "open" with only 1 DV.
Two "answers" to the question - a question that is either "unclear", or possibly a "duplicate" - have rewarded 2 users with a total 90 rep pts.
And (tangential) 7 UVs is quite an achievement when a large number of correct SO answers to good, answerable SO questions receive 0 UVs.


Supplemental
From this comment

What is the point? ... Is the question they asked “Solve this assignment for me?” or “Help me figure out these things I am trying to learn?”


My question to Meta is: Is it time to recognise that the allure of internet rep points is causing harm to the SO objective of being a searchable repository of quality answers to quality questions?
This is but one of myriad Q&A's that contribute nothing of value to the repository.
In my opinion, these only to clog-up the repository with wrong-or-inappropriate answers to poorly written questions.
I admit that I have inferred that this Q&A is a clear demonstration of the harmful effects of "rep point" acquisition.
To DV and VTC this aging question would do little at this time.
To DV one or both "answers" will do little, also.
Knocking 2 points off of a reaping of 70 or 20 points is (forgive the pun) pointless.
I've searched SO-Meta for "reputation" "harm" and "harmful", but have not found any discussions of this topic.
I've read many comments in numerous threads that allude to this consequence (becoming clogged-up to the point of uselessness) for SO.
But, I've found no specific thread discussing "ending the gameification of rep points."

Try it yourself
I used copy/paste to submit the title ONLY of OP's post to ChatGPT 3.5.
The AI responded with a short code sample that demonstrated the exact syntax that the OP's comment shows was the solution they sought.

1 I was recently cautioned -- by a moderator -- to use a comment to
"politely ask for clarification or more information. Do not presume to 'intuit' an OP's meaning. Do not answer badly written questions." [my paraphrase]

" Is it time to recognise that the allure of internet rep points is causing harm to the SO objective of being a searchable repository of quality answers to quality questions?" - yes, and it has been for quite a while - but not for any of the reasons you've mentioned. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387356/332043

You are way too deep into the technical side of things for meta, IMHO (emphasis on my opinion). I'd have tried to talk less about that one question and more about the issue you want answered (we really don't need to know all the stats, even if we do, they could be lumped at the bottom of your post). As is, it's hard to understand your exact thoughts/question about rep farming problem (I'd also steer clear of recent controversial incidents as they would only serve as distraction).

Related: A commitment to amend and move forward

You asked about acquiring rep points.  What about those points that folks already have? Are you suggesting everyone's should be erased?

@WJS I'm not bothered anymore. Like so many, I've grown inured to the site's social structure and the consequences thereof. (i.e. Stopped participating) The gradual deflation and eventual demise of the site will "erase" everyone's virtual rep points, anyway. Failure to respond to identified threats to "the community" has led to the site's reputation for toxicity and gaslighting. So it goes... May SO RIP...

See What motivates people to answer questions on Stack Exchange?. Reputation is a real, and significant motivator. To that end, it has been, and still is useful.
I'm not disputing that it has the real potential to also motivate problematic behaviours (lots of motivators have that problem). I'm also not saying it's the only possible motivator. And while I do believe that reputation can motivate seeking quality (answering canonicals is in theory supposed to be more "lucrative" in the long run. Emphasis on "in theory". With the current rep system, that's disputable in practice), it's better supplemented with other motivations (like caring about the mission of the platform- the usefulness of the resource we're building).
Zoe gave a good link to The Stack Exchange reputation system: What's working? What's not?. Coming back to the duplicates thing, I have a related answer there.

Appreciation for your time posting this answer. I've skimmed the linked pages. The debate has been raging since long before I arrived. Noted... Re: "other motivations (like caring about the mission of the platform" The site has low tolerance for what it deems to be "abusive behaviour"... And, yet... The Q&A case study I link to continues to receive at least one UV to an "answer" to a "question" that does NOT ask a discernable question... I'm advised to "let old-timers behave as they will" [my paraphrase]... It boggles the mind, it does...

@Fe2O3 from an extremely cursory glance at the linked Q&A, I don't see an issue, and honestly, that's as much attention into what seems to be like a big stumbling block to you as I care to give right now.

No, it is not time to go messing with "reputation" in any way.
The reason is simple:
Many users have invested uncountable hours generating content primarily for the domain specific recognition and perceived prestige of increasing their accumulated reputation tallies. This has sometimes been reinforced by off topic congratulatory messages from other users to individuals on their achievement of certain milestones: the first 100K, the next 100K, and even the 1M reputation point thresholds.
This commitment to a purpose causes an addictive positive feedback loop, the interruption or alteration of which may be harmful to some sensitive personalities.
In the interest of the well-being of those who've been with the site for a large fraction of its existence, the reputation scheme must stay as is.

Yes!, and as quickly as it can be done!
Tergiversators will do their level-best to denounce, deny, deflect and distract from the simplicity of a simple question that can/could be answered simply.
This answer gives an eloquent definition of the commonly understood meaning of the term "rep farming".
In contrast, here is a quote taken from a recently closed SO-Meta thread:

"I farm reputation by answering questions that are useful. My perception is that this will increase my reputation by getting more people to upvote my answers because [those answers] helped [those askers]." [emphasis mine]

Claims that it is ALSO "rep farming" to actually be fulfilling the stated purpose of SO
-- To be a searchable repository of quality answers to quality questions --
are little more than disingenuous, prevaricating attempts to muddy the water.
This site is not meant to be a technology-oriented version of  "Dragons' Den", "Shark Tank" or "Money Tigers" (national variations of choreographed but unscripted TV), in which a celebrity panel each express their 'take' on a subject, but spread across many episodes (separated by months or years).
The site and its members should be protecting and improving the value of the existing repository; not rewarding polluters who engage in "rep farming" behaviours.
Here is one Q&A from 2011 (13 years ago).
Here is another of virtually the same Q&A for a few weeks ago, the asker being a member who, similarly, could have found their answer by doing the most obvious bit of research. To wit: Carefully reading of the section of the man page directly related to their question. Please note the 4 UVs for the question and the 4 UVs - and an "accept" awarded to the answer.
In both instances, the solution to the asker's problem is clearly spelled out in the man page for sscanf(3) under "conversion specifiers", item [ (commonly called a scanset):

"To include a close bracket in the set, make it the first character after the open bracket or the circumflex; any other position will end the set."

I cannot be bothered to dig through the '0s or '00s of other versions of this same Q&A.
Please note the similarity in the titles of the two questions:

Escaping square bracket ] in sscanf
Negating brackets in a C scanf() scanset

FWIW: Last month's version has now been flagged as a duplicate.
But not before more "yummy rep points" had been awarded (with more to come?).

The behaviour of "rep farming" has not only clogged-up the SO site with almost uncountable duplications (instead of improvements where-and-when valuable). The harmful behaviour gazumps reputation from those who've previously contributed quality input to SO. This can only be seen as a self-defeating and selfish behaviour. As SO becomes less-and-less useful (because of its diluted and repetitive content), any perceived value of "SO reputation" earned is diminished.
Parenthetically: Why do long-serving, hi-rep members do this to their own efforts and contributions? Long-serving members should be the most capable of sensing that a posted question is-or-is-not likely to already be addressed by a Q&A currently in the repository. New users, and beginners in the field, are less likely to know how to selectively search and/or what terms to use to conduct an effective search.

Yes, it is time to end the allure of acquiring SO reputation as an end-in-itself.

Your answer fails to address how any the functionalitiy that rep has (permissions, mostly), would be replaced. This is just a "Booo rep bad!" answer.

@Cerbrus SO/SE presumed to be a cyberspace "meeting place" for highly intelligent people. Some time ago, smoking was commonplace. Then, some people started a movement to reduce the perceived public harm of smoking. Today, those who smoke are a pariah to be scorned. Lots of different "fronts" in the war on smoking... Ask some of the very intelligent engineers on this site to put forward proposals of workable implementation plans to shift the game on this site. Nothing will change if everyone does nothing. I asked a question on Meta hoping for a simple answer. Equivocation is all that came back.

"Ask some of the very intelligent engineers on this site to put forward proposals" I did give you feedback that you should be asking that very question here. Many people have already discussed "how to solve this problem before" and there have been suggestions given by the community to the company. The problem really is that the company isn't prioritizing this too much.

See this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387356/the-stack-exchange-reputation-system-whats-working-whats-not

@AbdulAzizBarkat It must be "The Company" that has cast (currently) 29 DV's on this Q&A... Laughable...

@Fe2O3 no, the community has cast downvotes on this question (Disclosure: I've voted neither way on this question). IMO that is because this question is discussing the wrong thing "Is it time to end the allure of acquiring SO "rep points"?" is not the correct question, the real question is "How do we end the allure of acquiring SO rep points?" you seem to be insisting on focusing on the former without discussing the latter (which is the more important discussion).

"a cyberspace "meeting place" for highly intelligent people" No. That's not the purpose of SO. Far from it. SO is a repository of quality Q&A. The fact that users contribute is not relevant.

"Today, those who smoke are a pariah to be scorned" That's a gross exaggeration.

"Equivocation is all that came back." Eh, maybe it's time to look in the mirror, @Fe203. "Equivocation" is exactly how I would describe your writing.
